# Updating global variable in django from external program

Tags: django

Application running in django, apache, python and mysql:

I want to create global variable which I should be able to update from external python script may be using a cron job.

The the solution I think of... is having a webpage which updates that variable and then call this through a python script.

Any cleaner solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a huge variety of inter-process communication ("IPC") mechanisms, but I don't believe any of them will be easier, safer or "cleaner" than going through HTTP (which is basically what "a webpage which updates that variable" amounts to!-) -- all of your settings are already prepared to handle HTTP ("web";-) interactions, after all!  Alternatives such as having the cron job update MySQL directly are *less* "clean" and more complicated to integrate with the rest of your application (your app would have to be "polling" the DB regularly about that one variable -- eek!-).